# Bulk update Google Sheet with python Table

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to pull data from a website, create a table, and then store that table in a Google spreadsheet. I have successfully copied the data from the site and can send data to google cell by cell. However, Google's API limits the number of requests, so I'm trying to work around it by sending the data in bulk rather than as single requests. Any ideas on how to do that? Here's a snippet of code showing what I have at the moment.

I tried creating a table to store the data, but I had trouble sending it to google sheets. I'm currently running Python 3 in PyCharm using Selenium for web browser automation.

```
for a in range(1,row_count + 1):
    for b in range(1,col_count + 1):
        final_path = first_part + str(a) + second_part + str(b) + third_part
        table_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
        #print(table_data)
        sheetone.update_cell(a , b , table_data)
```

I want to scrape the website and temporarily store the data within my script then send all of the data out as a single request.

"message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:487815375845'.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to put the values to the Spreadsheet by one API call.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to put and get values for the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, at first, the data is created in the for loop, and then, the created data is put to the Spreadsheet using `update_cells`.

#### Modified script:

```
data = []  # Added
for a in range(1,row_count + 1):
    for b in range(1,col_count + 1):
        final_path = first_part + str(a) + second_part + str(b) + third_part
        table_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
        #print(table_data)
        data.append(gspread.models.Cell(a, b, table_data))  # Modified

sheetone.update_cells(data)  # Added
```

#### References:

- [Updating Cells](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#updating-cells)
- [gspread.models.Cell(row, col, value='')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=gspread.models.Worksheet#gspread.models.Cell)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.